# Failed opening required 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php'

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I uploaded the Facebook folder from SDK and wrote code like this:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
```

And browser gives me this error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php55u/lib/php')

Comment: It means it is not able to locate Facebook/FacebookSession.php. Are you using SDK 5? Because in my fresh SDK I downloaded does not contain FacebookSession.php at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have the latest version of the sdk, but this code applies to an older version of Facebook SDK. In the latest version of the Facebook SDK there is no 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php'. If you have the latest version of the SDK, use this instead

```
    require_once("Facebook/autoload.php");
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $app_id,
        'app_secret' => $app_sec,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as a charm! But now it throws **Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()** when I'm trying to execute my request `$response = $request -> execute();`

Comment: If you have a valid access token try `$response = $fb->get('/me')` and then `$userNode = $response->getGraphUser()` to get the result in an object. You are using codes for a previous version of the sdk.

Comment: Actually getting response from request is from facebook site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/groups#publish

Comment: Now the error is _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$userNode' (T_VARIABLE)_ here's the code: http://pastebin.com/Vinn9cqg

Comment: Why are you using old version code? Look at the Facebook documentation of the latest version. And you are getting this error because you are missing a `;`

Comment: Now it is _Fatal error: Call to a member function getGraphUser() on a non-object_ HTML: http://pastebin.com/VQGzmW9Z PHP: http://pastebin.com/xzx43vpa

Comment: Are you trying to post in a group?

Comment: You really should look at the documentations. I don't know from where you got those codes. Take a look at [login with facebook and getting an access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) And [post something in user timeline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi)

Comment: I'm not trying to post, I'm trying to create group: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/groups#publish by using PHP. I already have read that and did something wrong, thats why Im asking you.

Comment: And by the way, the link you are referring, those codes are out dated. If you really want to use them, you'll have to down grade your sdk version.

Comment: I have no intent to use outdated ones, I justs didn't know that they were outdated. Where can I get updated ones? Btw. you explained that great in the code, thank you very much! The token that is used in there, does it come like by default or I should pass that from login function, via href link?

Comment: The token should come from a logged in user, see the facebook documentation. You'll find it in the "Getting started" section. And when you log in a user, you must request permission to create a group.

Comment: Ye I know about the token but how do I request the permission?

Comment: The documentation says that it needs an "App Access Token". I am not too familiar with this. But if you want to know how to request the permissions, see the code in "Obtaining an access token from redirect" section of [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) page. Notice the `$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];` line. This is where you add permissions

Comment: The token is obtained as it says here: http://mattpilz.com/facebook-graph-access-token-photo-album/ and now it finally works, thanks! Now I want to delete the group with this code http://pastebin.com/yc8QwDWF first it was saying that I cant delete non-empty group so I left the group and now with 0 users it says "Param group must be a valid Group ID" im getting group id through get as you can see and it worked earlier when it was saying that group is non empty but now it does not

Comment: And you said that I'm using outdated api. Where can I obtain updated one?